# How to efficiently create label columns out of existing columns without for loop and drop them afterwords

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame looking like this:

```
 A   B   C   D
 2   5   0   9
 2   0   8   0
 0   0   8   9
 2   0   8   0
 0   5   0   9
 2   0   8   9
 0   5   0   9  
 2   5   8   0
```

I want to check each value in a column and create a new one out of that column such that each row of the new column will be 1 if the value is greater 0 and 0 otherwise

I did it using a for loop this way:

```
 #Generate a data frame example
 df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(5, size=(10, 8)), columns = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E","F","G", "H"])

 # create a label out of it
 for label in df.columns.values:
     df['label_' + label] = df[label].apply(lambda a: 0  if  a==0 else 1)
     df.drop(label, axis=1)
```

My questions are:

1- How can I do the same task but without a for loop?

2- How can I drop the columns after manipualting them? I already tried `.drop(label,
    axis=1)` but it did nto work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you could do -

```
df_out  = (df>0).astype(int)
df_out.columns = ['label_'+i for i in df.columns]
```

A vectorized way to create those new labels, would be using [`NumPy's char supported functions`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.core.defchararray.add.html) -

```
df_out.columns = np.core.add('label_',df.columns)
```

Or a nice one-liner as [`suggested by @Ted Petrou`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44806697/how-to-efficiently-create-label-columns-out-of-existing-columns-without-for-loop/44806811?noredirect=1#comment76593886_44806811) -

```
(df>0).astype(int).add_prefix('label_')
```

Comment: or `df.add_prefix('label_')`

Answer (score 2):

Another option...

```
df2 = df.mask(df != 0).fillna('1').add_prefix('label_')
print(df2)

  label_A label_B label_C label_D label_E label_F label_G label_H
0       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1
1       1       1       0       1       1       1       0       0
2       1       0       0       1       1       0       0       1
3       1       1       1       0       1       1       1       0
4       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1
5       1       0       0       1       1       1       1       0
6       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1
7       1       0       1       0       1       0       1       0
8       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1
9       0       1       1       1       0       1       1       1
```